# Eclipse content assist behavior. Can it be more like Apatana or phpEdit

Tags: php, eclipse, content-assist

I am trying to make the switch to eclipse and for the most part I am happy, however this is one behavior that is quite bothersome to me. Let's say I am calling function

foo (arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4)

when I type foo(  - the function insight pops up and shows me the parameter list.

As soon as I start typing the value of the first parameter it goes away. Now I have to use my mouse to hover over the function name to see the next argument.

I am coming from PHPEdit and in that system it would highlight each parameter as I typed and did not require me to break away from the keyboard to use the mouse, which is quite annoying.

Is there any setting that can be tweaked or am I stuck with this?  I noticed that apatana studio works the way I want it to. Maybe a plugin of some sort?

I want to love eclipse, but this is a deal breaker (having to use the mouse). I'm sure it's just because I don't understand it.  I tried hitting ctrl+space and that did not show me the parameter list.

Another issue I have is the function insight seems to be picky as to when it even decides to show up. I'll type $string = str_replace and it will not show up. I'll simply delete str_replace and start typing again and it may or may not show up the second time (It does not show up about 40% of the time)

Ok thanks. Hopefully we can work it out, because I do enjoy some of the features of this platform.

--EDIT-- version is 4.2.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tried this with the Eclipse 4.2 Java editor.

If you hit the Enter key after you type a parameter, it shows the next parameter in a tool tip.

Let me know if it works the same way for PHP.

Comment: Thanks, I think that is livable!  I can get used to that.